# Find a basis for the subspace of polynomials $H \subset P_2\mathbb{(R)}$ where:

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the subspace of polynomials $H \subset P_2\mathbb{(R)}$ where:

$\int_{-1}^{1} p(x) dx =0$ for $p \in H$

Give its dimension

This is what I have done:

$p(x) = ax^2 + bx+c$

I integrated as shown to get:
$2a/3+2c=0$

So the integral stands if and only if $c=-a/3$

So all $p \in H$ is of the form:
$p(x) = ax^2 +bx -a/3$

such that

Basis: $(3x^2-1),(3x)$

Dimension: $2$

Am I completely wrong? or close?

Comment: It is correct. The $3x$ could be replaced by $x$, but it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

An (orthogonal) basis for this subspace is the [Legendre polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html) $P_i(x)$ orthogonal to the $P_0(x)=1.$